# Android: Hardware Scaler

Tags: opengl, android, gpu, hardware-acceleration

I was reading through this: [using-hardware-scaler-for-performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html) and am a little confused by it.  It says all you need to do to invoke the scaler is to set it like so:

```
surfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
surfaceView.getHolder().setFixedSize(1280, 720);
```

They says to use a fixed size for all devices.  On my Google Nexus 10 (which has a resolution of 2560 x 1600).  I've used 1280*800.  It then goes on to say that the system will scale it to match the device's actual resolution.

So this is what I get:

[image]

What am I missing here? Unfortunately the above link says that examples will be added soon but as yet there is nothing.

Comment: I just had the same problem and I made a silly mistake: I specified that lower resolution both on the surface view holder via `setFixedSize` *and* I halved the resolution in `onSurfaceChanged` and set the view port on the OpenGL ES context basically to a quarter of the available screen estate. Visually it gives exactly the same result as in your illustrations above. Just make sure that you pass on the `width` and `height` values in `onSurfaceChanged` as they are to `glViewPort`. They will be the same as specified with `setFixedSize`